# Determine coordinate of a point on unit sphere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres

> Let $S$ be unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ center at $O(0,0,0)$. Let $A=(x_1,y_1,z_1),B = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$ be two points lying on the sphere $S$. Let $M$ be center of $AB$ which lies on the geodesics $AB$. Find the coordinate of P on sphere which lie on plane perpendicular with $AB$ and angle $(MOP) = \alpha$.

[image]

I know how to find the coordinate of the point $M$ but have not idea to find coordinate of $P$ in term of coordinate $A,B$ and angle $\alpha$. Can anyone give me a hint? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross-product
$(B-M)X(O-M)
$
will produce a vector
perpendicular to
$MB$ and $MO$.

Adjust its length
to make
$\frac{|PM|}{|MO|}
=\tan(\alpha)
$.

Comment: but it does not give the coordinate of P, and OPM is not a right angle